# Remote shutdown

Tags: windows, mac, remote-access

Having a MAC OS X Server on a network for all windows computer,how to do the Remote Shutdown  for another computer on the network.

`shutdown /m \\Computername /s /t 0` is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have Samba installed on your OS X server, and then you can run:

```
net rpc shutdown -I IPADDRESS -U USERNAME%PASSWORD
```

Note that these tools are not installed as a part of OS X 10.7 (and I assume higher, when there is higher) by default. [For more details, see this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/316252/can-anyone-confirm-that-the-net-commands-net-rpc-net-ads-etc-were-removed).